# How to call constructor function from within itself?

Tags: node.js

Good day,

I want a function to check if there are any files inside a folder, if there is no folder, make the folder and then run itself (function) again.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const writeFileAtomic = require('write-file-atomic');

class DataHandler {
    constructor() {
    }
}

DataHandler.prototype.checkDB = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir('./database', function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code = 'ENOENT') {
                    fs.mkdir('./database', () => {
                        return this.checkDB;
                    })
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            }
            if (files) {
                console.log(files)
            }
        })
    })
}

module.exports = DataHandler;
```

I get errors using this, saying this.checkDB is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix maybe is to save `this` in a variable:

```
DataHandler.prototype.checkDB = function() {
    var dataHandler = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir('./database', function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code = 'ENOENT') {
                    fs.mkdir('./database', () => {
                        return dataHandler.checkDB;
                    })
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            }
            if (files) {
                console.log(files)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

A VERY basic explanation:

In javascript, when you put `this` inside of a `function(){}` it gets assigned to that `function`'s object. Then, when you called `fs.readdir(...., function(... { ...`  the keyword/variable `this` was binded to that `function()`'s object.. I recommend you this read: [this - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

That binding does not happen with arrow functions, so, if you're curious there's another fix for your problem. You would need to replace `function (err, files)` with `(err, files) =>`, like this:

```
DataHandler.prototype.checkDB = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir('./database', (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code = 'ENOENT') {
                    fs.mkdir('./database', () => {
                        return this.checkDB;
                    })
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            }
            if (files) {
                console.log(files)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: This worked, however I am curious why? Why can I not call the function from within itself like you usually can. How does it being a constructor change things?

Comment: Hi Bob, that's a bit complex to explain. I tried my best on a post edit. Please check it out :)

Comment: Ohhhh that makes sense. Thank you very much! I see where I misunderstood 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the object this refers to the Object created with the `new Promise(..` I would suggest to `log.console(this)` and check what it contains